# How to link a (which is downloaded and build while bitbaking)library in a folder to files in u-boot using yocto in beaglebone black?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, beagleboneblack, u-boot, tpm

I am trying to integrate cryptoauthlib library (https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib Microchip library for Trust Platform module devices like ATECC608B) to beaglebone while bitbaking using yocto project.
My cryptoauthlib has been downloaded and build successfully . Now my buid_bbb/tmp/work/beaglebone../ has below folders.

1. cryptoauthlib1
2. u-boot
   .
   .
   Now I am trying to add
   ..
   #include "cryptoauthlib.h"
   #include "secure_boot.h"
   ..
   in bootm.c file(which is in u-boot/1_../git/arch/arm/lib/)
   But I am getting compiling errors . How do I include the cryptoauthlib library to my u-boot files.

In userspace, when I create a program helloworld.c, I compile it using ..
`gcc helloworld.c  -L/home/cryptoauthlib/lib/ -lcryptoauth -I/home/cryptoauthlib/lib -I/home/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/`

I have tried adding CFLAGS into Makefile (arch/arm/lib/Makefile)

```
 ccflags-y += -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/usr/include/cryptoauthlib/
 ccflags-y += -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/usr/include/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/
```

and my recipe-sysroot folder has cryptoauthlib folder, and has

```
*cryptoauthlib.h
*app/secure_boot/secure_boot.h
```

When I bitbake u-boot, I get Error saying:No secure_boot.h found.
Even I tried giving *#include "app/secure_boot/secure_boot.h"*, the error persists

when I add `EXTRA_OEMAKE += "CFLAGS ='-i${WORKDIR}/.."` or even `EXTRA_OEMAKE +="INCLUDE_PATH='-I${WORKDIR}/.."`  in u-boot.inc and `bitbake u-boot.inc` I get error..(even) cryptoauthlib.h not found
This is in my cryptoauthlib1.bb:

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/build/libcryptoauth.so ${D}${libdir}
    ln -sf libcryptoauth.so ${D}${libdir}/libcryptoauth.so.${PV}
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/cryptoauthlib/
    cp -r ${WORKDIR}/git/lib/*.h ${D}${includedir}/cryptoauthlib/
 
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/git/app/secure_boot/*.h ${D}${includedir}/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/
 }
```

But I get error like

/home/testing1/Desktop/jeffy/build_bbb/tmp/work/beaglebone_yocto-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2019.07-r0/git/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c:36:10: fatal error: secure_boot/secure_boot.h: No such file or directory
36 | #include <secure_boot.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make -f /home/testing1/Desktop/jeffy/build_bbb/tmp/work/beaglebone_yocto-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2019.07-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=drivers/block

Comment: Have you added your library as a build dependency for u-boot in a bbappend file? Something like `DEPENDS += " cryptoauthlib1"`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620562/skandigraun yes, i have added it . My u-boot_2019.07.bb has the following

require u-boot-common.inc
require u-boot.inc
DEPENDS +="bc-native dtc-native"
DEPENDS += "cryptoauthlib1"

But still I am getting linking errors

Comment: Can you edit your post with the exact error?
When you add it to `DEPENDS`, the library should be present in the recipe's `recipe-sysroot-native` folder (sysroot), where you can check if all files are at the correct place.

Comment: @skandigraun ,..Now you have mentioned , I have modified the cryptoauthlib1.bb file to install the headers . 
I will edit my post with the error now

Comment: Well, that seems to be a possible clue. You are including from `secure_boot` folder, but your headers are installed in `app/secure_boot` folder.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620562/skandigraun, even when I do 
..
#include <app/secure_boot/secure_boot.h>
..

I get the fatal error:app/secure_boot/secure_boot.h : No such file or directory.

But I can see the secure_boot.h  in u-boot/1_2019.07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620562/skandigraun My bootm.c file is :
   .. <br/>
    #include "cryptoauthlib.h"<br/>
    #inclucde "secure_boot.h"<br/>
    ..<br/>

my recipe-sysroot/usr/include/ has cryptoauthlib folder in which 
1.cryptoauthlib.h
2.app/secure_boot/secure_boot.h

My Makefile for this is  
ccflags-y += -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/usr/include/cryptoauthlib/
ccflags-y += -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/usr/include/cryptoauthlib/app/secure_boot/

But when I bitbake , I get Fatal error: secure_boot.h :no such file or directory. 
There is no error for cryptoauthlib.h

Comment: `${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}` is a destination folder, not a source one. Try using `${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include/cryptoauthlib` or something like that

Comment: I still get same error@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620562/skandigraun

Comment: Just to be sure, are you adding this to `EXTRA_OEMAKE` variable (or `CFLAGS`), like `EXTRA_OEMAKE += "-I${WORKDIR}/..."` or are you creating patch to change the Makefile? (It should be the prior, using Yocto variables)

Comment: I have added  "ccflags-y += -I{WORKDIR}/ .. " to Makfile and created a patch and added it to u-boot files folder (patch is added to SRCI_URI_append variable in u-boot_2019.07.bbappend)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620562/skandigraun when I add
    ' EXTRA_OEMAKE +=  "CFLAGS ='-i${WORKDIR}/.." '
or even 
    'EXTRA_OEMAKE +="INCLUDE_PATH='-I${WORKDIR}/.."', '
in u-boot.inc and **bitbake u-boot.inc**
I get error..(even) cryptoauthlib.h not found